# Is this an ambiguous use of "prior to" to convey logical precedence?

Tags: phrase-meaning, ambiguity, logic

Consider the following sentence:

> Volcanic eruptions could not account for the high rate of the global collapse of ecosystems prior to the K-T extinction event.

The usage of "prior to" is strange. Taken literally, there was no collapse of ecosystems before the extinction event. The only explanation is that "prior to" is a logical precedent. In other words, without the global collapse, there wouldn't be an extinction event, and if the ecosystems hadn't collapsed this quickly, it probably wouldn't be a mass extinction event, because many species would probably not become extinct.

Using the phrase "prior to" is a valid way to express logical precedence. In this case, it seems ambiguous because it could be interpreted in a temporal sense and would confuse people.

**Is the sentence phrased poorly or not?** (Is the logical usage of "prior to" too advanced/obscure to appear on the SAT?)

Motivation and context for asking is that the sentence is adapted from a *correct* answer for a question provided on a [SAT practice test, see Question 50](https://cdn.princetonreview.com/ResourceContent/SAT_2016/books/SATPrep2023/BASIC/SAT_Prep_2023_Practice_Test_5.pdf) (PDF).

Comment: You say the sentence was adapted, but you may have changed its meaning a little, and there is no context. I *suspect* this is referring to a "slow collapse" theory (the "event" would have been about 800,000 year time scale) based in part on the Deccan Traps and before there was conclusive proof of the impact theory. Some thought the impact might have exacerbated Deccan eruption activity, but the sentence you present sounds like a critique of the Deccan Traps idea and favoring the sudden impact event as primary cause. I do think "prior to" in there causes some confusion.

Comment: The original sentence is "volcanic eruptions could not account for the speed
of global changes prior to the extinction event." Yes, it does have to do with the Deccan Traps. The question is Question 50 from https://cdn.princetonreview.com/ResourceContent/SAT_2016/books/SATPrep2023/BASIC/SAT_Prep_2023_Practice_Test_5.pdf

Comment: That makes a little more sense as it is talking about setting conditions that then led to the collapse. These changes would (of course) come before the act.

Comment: "Global changes" makes sense. Why is "ecosystems" introduced? The word *prior* works fine in the original.

Comment: "ecosystems" is added for the sake of context. Also, the collapse of ecosystems is literally part of a mass extinction, rather than the cause of it.

Comment: The [acceptable] sentence as given by OP [t + 1 hour version] may be paraphrased 'The rate of the global collapse of ecosystems prior to the K-T extinction event was high; this  high rate cannot be accounted for by volcanic eruptions [alone].' I'm struggling to provide a plausible alternative reading.

Comment: Yes, that is a way to rephrase the sentence. However you did not address the problem of "prior to" at all.

Comment: @ZongshuWu I took the liberty of editing your question. Some is merely formatting for English SE. Some is more subjective. As you are a new contributor here, PLEASE be aware that you are free to reject some or all of my edits! I can help you with that if you do not feel that my edits are an improvement or if you feel that they change your intended meaning.

Comment: There was a massive ecological turnover in North America prior to the k-t event as evidenced in the megaflora fossil record. This is likely what is being referenced. So I'm going with "no".

Comment: It's not just the sequencing preposition 'prior to' that can give rise to ambiguity. 'The museum possessed few signs of research done on history before the 1500s' = 'The museum possessed few signs of research done before the 1500s on history' or 'The museum possessed few signs of research done on [history before the 1500s]'. Or even 'Before the 1500s, the museum possessed few signs of research done on history.' Does the PP refer to research done, the period of history under consideration, or the development of the museum?

Answer (score 4):

I lack the science knowledge to even follow the objection. But let's substitute other variables.

> Boredom could not account for the high rate of students dropping out prior to the final exam.

The most reasonable interpretation is: A lot of students dropped out *prior to* (i.e., *before*) the finals. And it wasn't just because of boredom.

There are a few other possible interpretations, but they would be perverse unless context prompted us into that understanding. For instance, "Before the final exam happened, boredom wasn't a good explanation. But after the exam, it was." If this meaning were intended, it could be better served by reordering the syntax, like "Prior to the final exam, boredom could not account for the high rate of students dropping out."

I think you've let scientific confusion cause linguistic confusion. "Prior to" just means "before," plain and simple. Any logical and causal implications in the sentence are the result of other phrases. The original sentence was "Volcanic eruptions could not account for the speed
of global changes prior to the extinction event." This makes no overt causal implications about the "changes" and the "event." "Prior to" is just a marker on a timeline.

Comment: This is a bad analogy. Here, the sentence unambiguously means "dropping out _before_ the final exam", but in the original sentence, the global collapse of ecosystems does NOT occur before the mass extinction, because it is a part of the mass extinction.

Comment: Here, there is no way that "prior to" means a simple temporal precedence (or perhaps the question writer just got it wrong). My mom, who is a philosopher, thinks that this must be a logical precedence, as I have explained in my question.

Comment: @ZongshuWu I finally took the trouble to read the excerpt. I think that the sentence "Volcanic eruptions could not account for the speed of global changes prior to the extinction event" is drawing a distinction between the extinction itself and its cause. You've created an incorrect sentence by substituting "collapse of ecosystems" for "global changes." The "changes" *caused* extinction. These changes, Passage 1's panel concluded, were rapid. However rapid, they happened "before" the extinction event, as its cause.

Comment: Thanks! Although this is still a bit suspicious because the passage emphasizes the speed of _ecosystem collapse_, not the speed of some generic "global change". Oh well, the Princeton Review's practice tests aren't that high quality anyway.

Comment: *"This is a bad analogy"*???!!! - It's a *perfect* analogy!

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Andy's answer:
The sentence given implies these two facts:

1. Before (prior to) the K-T extinction event, there was a high rate of
   global collapse of ecosystems;
2. Volcanic eruptions could not account for that high rate of collapse.

The sentence is well formed for expressing these facts. Your objection seems to be to fact 1 on scientific, grounds - if fact 1 were not true, the sentence would be incorrect or invalid but not badly phrased.

In regard to whether this is a bad question, and speaking from a great deal of experience with and study of the SAT, you have not given the relevant information. SAT questions are based on the readings provided on the test, and whether they are confusing *should* be driven by whether you read and understood the passage provided. Since we can't see the passage, we can't provide feedback on whether the question is good.